# How to create has_many_and_belongs_to association for conditions on a different table in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, associations

I have a **users** table for `User` model which is created via devise, **roles** table for Role model. Both `User` and `Role` are associated with HABTM.

```
roles:
id: integer
name: string

roles_users:
user_id:integer
roles_id:integer
```

I have three roles: admin, manager, and reporter.

Now, I create a `Team` model which looks like this:

```
teams:
name: string
```

I want to have many managers for one team.

So, if I create a team:

```
t = Team.create(name: 'Football')
```

then I would like to fetch all the managers( users who have role: 'manager') who handles the team 'Football'. So, I created HABTM between Team and User.

```
teams_users:
team_id:integer
user_id:integer
```

I need an association: `managers` inside `Team` model. But, so far this code isn't working:

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  validates :name, presence: true

  has_and_belongs_to_many :managers, class_name: 'User', association_foreign_key: 'user_id', conditions: joins(:roles, :roles_users).where('roles_users.role_id = ?', Role.select('id, name').find_by_name('manager').id)

end
```

When I do: `t.managers` I get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Association named 'roles' was not found on Team; perhaps you misspelled it?
    from /Users/suryat/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.2.17/lib/active_record/associations/join_dependency.rb:112:in `build'
    from /Users/suryat/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.2.17/lib/active_record/associations/join_dependency.rb:123:in `block in build'
    from /Users/suryat/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.2.17/lib/active_record/associations/join_dependency.rb:122:in `each'
    from /Users/suryat/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.2.17/lib/active_record/associations/join_dependency.rb:122:in `build'
    from /Users/suryat/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.2.17/lib/active_record/associations/join_dependency.rb:18:in `initialize'
    from /Users/suryat/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.2.17/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:358:in `new'
    from /Users/suryat/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.2.17/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:358:in `build_joins'
    from /Users/suryat/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.2.17/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:266:in `build_arel'
    from /Users/suryat/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.2.17/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:260:in `arel'
    from /Users/suryat/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.2.17/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:29:in `respond_to?'
    from /Users/suryat/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.2.17/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:161:in `interpolate'
    from /Users/suryat/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.2.17/lib/active_record/associations/association_scope.rb:8:in `interpolate'
    from /Users/suryat/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.2.17/lib/active_record/associations/association_scope.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in add_constraints'
    from /Users/suryat/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.2.17/lib/active_record/associations/association_scope.rb:76:in `each'
    from /Users/suryat/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.2.17/lib/active_record/associations/association_scope.rb:76:in `block in add_constraints'
    from /Users/suryat/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.2.17/lib/active_record/associations/association_scope.rb:39:in `each'
    from /Users/suryat/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.2.17/lib/active_record/associations/association_scope.rb:39:in `each_with_index'
    from /Users/suryat/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.2.17/lib/active_record/associations/association_scope.rb:39:in `add_constraints'
    from /Users/suryat/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.2.17/lib/active_record/associations/association_scope.rb:31:in `scope'
    from /Users/suryat/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.2.17/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:99:in `association_scope'
    from /Users/suryat/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.2.17/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:88:in `scoped'
    from /Users/suryat/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.2.17/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:382:in `find_target'
    from /Users/suryat/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.2.17/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:335:in `load_target'
    from /Users/suryat/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.2.17/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:44:in `load_target'
    from /Users/suryat/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.2.17/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:89:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/suryat/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /Users/suryat/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /Users/suryat/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in
```

What am I doing wrong? Any suggestions?

Comment: What is not working? What do you get with `t.managers`? How is it different from your expected output?

Comment: see the updated question. I've added the error trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setup the association as below:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :managers, class_name: 'User', 
                        association_foreign_key: 'user_id', 
                        include: :roles, 
                        conditions: ['roles_users.role_id = ?', Role.select('id, name').find_by_name('manager').id]
```

You are getting the error as `Association named 'roles' was not found on Team` because you tried to call association of `roles` and `roles_users` on `teams` (with the `conditions` option) and `teams` is not associated with either of them.

What you need in this case is to specify a *second-order association* using `include` option so the association of `roles` is applied on `users` table instead of `teams`

Comment: Yes, almost there. The only thing is it gives this error: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'roles_users.role_id' in 'where clause': SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `teams`  WHERE (`roles_users`.role_id = 2)`. It is taking "roles_users.role_id" whole as a column. Any idea?

Comment: Never mind. I've got it working. Thanks for your help. Update this: `has_and_belongs_to_many :managers, class_name: 'User', association_foreign_key: 'user_id', include: [:roles], conditions: ['roles_users.role_id = ?', Role.select('id, name').find_by_name('manager').id]` in your code so I can accept it as final answer. Again, thank you for pointing out that `include` option, I entirely missed it.

Comment: Good catch! Also now you can directly specify `include: :roles` instead of `include: [:roles]`

Comment: You need to remove `where` clause too. Since it's first level active record query. Hence it treats `roles_users.role_id` as a column. Update it in your answer please.